# Android: Help screen wizard to guide user

Tags: android, android-layout

First of all, I have done my search on **SO** and **google** but haven't got any desired solution which fits to my problem. And I am not asking to provide me the code. I want suggestions how I solve my problem.

So my problem is, I have to create help wizard for 2-3 `activities` to guide user through the `activity` screen. I have created the help screen but its not fitting to screen if I check it on different resolution phones, means the text and images which I am showing to guide user to how to operate the app.

So need some suggestions like how I create my screen.

Here are **2 solution** which I am thinking of:

1. Create another activity with same layout.
2. Take high resolution screenshot of activity then modify it with adding text & images and show that image on screen.

Or if you have any other suggestion I would appreciate it.

One of my code for help wizard screen layout is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:background="@color/black_actionBar"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <com.AppName.utils.ButtonRegularFont
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/back" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.AppName.utils.TextViewRegularFont
        style="@style/textviews_whiteFont_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="Images" />

    <com.AppName.utils.ImageViewSettings
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@drawable/menu" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.AppName.utils.ButtonRegularFont
            style="@style/tabView_button_style"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hotel" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_images_hotel"
            style="@style/viewLineDisabled"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        style="@style/tabview_divider"
        android:layout_width="2dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.AppName.utils.ButtonRegularFont
            style="@style/tabView_button_style"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Rooms" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_images_rooms"
            style="@style/viewLineDisabled"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_selector"
    android:prompt="@string/select_room"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<com.AppName.utils.ButtonRegularFont
    style="@style/buttonStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:text="Add Image"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <org.askerov.dynamicgrid.DynamicGridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp" />

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"/>

    <com.AppName.utils.TextViewCircular 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="To start dragging an image just long press on any image and then it can be editable to drag to any position."/>
</FrameLayout>

<com.AppName.utils.ButtonRegularFont
    style="@style/buttonStyle_CheckedList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:text="Submit" />
```

Here is the image:

[image]

In above image the arrow is showing correctly with text but in some phone it won't show as it showing in the image.

Comment: A couple of tips for better questions, since you seem to have had some downvotes recently. Firstly, please do not add voting commentary into your questions (either requests not to downvote, or requests to explain downvotes) - these do not belong in posts. You can put these in comments if you really must, but I think they are a waste of time. Also, please don't use the quote device `>` as a general highlighter - this is not what it is for. Quotes are explicitly for material that comes from someone/somewhere else, like manual excerpts, error messages, speech, etc.

Comment: And who are whose teaching me all these????

Comment: I am not asking who is the downvoters??? I have mentioned that voting commentary because after asking question i was getting downvoted so i edited the question and updated it with votting commentary.

Comment: Right, OK. And I am saying that discussion about voting does not belong in questions - add it to comments instead please. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking high resolution images will increase you APK size so its better not to go with it. To make a screen Wizard you can use [ShowTipsView](https://github.com/fredericojssilva/ShowTipsView) Library . so you will not have to use full screen images to show the wizard.

Comment: Ok, let me look at the library url you have provided and would revert back to you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many libraries that you can use to do this.

[First-](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1132)

[Second-](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)